How to place node js-libp2p on hosting with?
I have relay node.
let libp2p = await createLibp2p({
  addresses: {
    listen: [
        '/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/0/ws'
    ]
  },
  transports: [
    webTransport(),
    webSockets({
      filter: filters.all
    })
  ],
  connectionEncryption: [noise()],
  streamMuxers: [yamux(), mplex()],
  services: {
    http: http(),
    identify: identify(),
    relay: circuitRelayServer({
      reservations: {
        maxReservations: Infinity
      }
    })
  },
  connectionManager: {
    minConnections: 0
  }
})


I have a relay node js-libp2p.
When I run it. It receives a multiaddress
'/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/0/ws'
This is enough for me for local development.
I need to place this node on a hosting.
So that it can be accessed via a public port.
(By the website address)
But when I deploy, the hosting does not see open ports for listening.
I tried to find transport for http requests, but didn't find anything similar.
Tried to run with http server on node.js or  express server.
Is there any mechanism for proxying a request from a site to '/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/0/ws' nodes?
Is it possible to access a node via path http://localhost:7654 ?
